# VS2013 error: PointCloudLibrary 1.8.0 member pcl::SAC_SAMPLE_SIZE

Tags: point-cloud-library

I am using PointCloudLibrary 1.8.0 RC2 and Visual Studio 2013.  When I compiled my project, the following error appeared:

> error C4996: 'pcl::SAC_SAMPLE_SIZE': This map is deprecated and is
>   kept only to prevent breaking existing user code. Starting from PCL
>   1.8.0 model sample size is a protected member of the SampleConsensusModel class   C:\Program
>   Files\PCL_1_8_0\PCL\include\pcl-1.8\pcl\sample_consensus\model_types.h    100 1

I tried to set "SDL check" to No but this error persists.

Comment: can you add the code throwing the error ? (at least in which context are you using it and which part of PCL are you working with ?)

Comment: I'm using it in SampleConsensusInitialAlignment, in SampleConsensusPrerejective and in ICP. With PCL 1.7.2 I didn't have this error. The error comes from model_types.h which is in PCL

Comment: hunt down the part of code that is throwing this error and post it. w/o that, every suggestion will be just a blind guess.

Comment: namespace pcl
{
  const static std::map<pcl::SacModel, unsigned int>
  PCL_DEPRECATED("This map is deprecated and is kept only to prevent breaking "
                 "existing user code. Starting from PCL 1.8.0 model sample size "
                 "is a protected member of the SampleConsensusModel class")
  SAC_SAMPLE_SIZE (sample_size_pairs, sample_size_pairs + sizeof (sample_size_pairs) / sizeof (SampleSizeModel));
}